# Is Visio page have the GUID?

Tags: vba, visio

Visio Shape object have ID and [UniqueID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) properties.

ID is a counter, UniqueID is a GUID.

Visio Page have only [ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766565%28v=office.14%29.aspx) propery.

**Is it a some GUID for Page**, auto generated by Visio by default (because my app can't modify the document)?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Try:

`page.PageSheet.UniqueID(visGetOrMakeGUID)`

It's like the one you have for shapes. But for pages. [See more details on `UniqueID` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767736.aspx)

Comment: This operation recreates the GUID's every time. By default, PageSheet have empty GUID, is it ?

Comment: Each `UniqueID(visGetOrMakeGUID)` generates the new GUID

Comment: Check the docs.. link in the reply. It works the same for pages and shapes. Just tried: `ActivePage.PageSheet.UniqueID(visGetOrMakeGUID)`- always returns the same GUID. Am I missing something?

Comment: If think I need to save the doc after `MakeGUID`

Comment: Now done, Saving does store the generated guid. But for my task I need the guid what already exists in visio doc, because my app can't modify the doc.

Comment: The guis do not exist by default (same for shapes, btw)... You can make sure that they do not exist by e.g. saving file as XML and checking it's content - no guids by default.